# Why doesn't a laser emit black body radiation?

Tags: laser, thermal-radiation

While deriving A and B coefficients we use Planck's law of blackbody radiation, but the spectrum obtained from the laser is not that of a blackbody because we get a very small band of light as output. My question is why are we not getting blackbody radiation spectrum?

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564727/) does not answer my question by the way, because my question is why it isn't blackbody radiation even if in the calculations we used it, and not why or how quasi-monochromaticity is obtained.

I have seen people argue physically why stimulated emission occurs theoretically at a particular frequency, but what I don't understand why  $u(\omega)$ being a blackbody radiation thing doesn't prevent or contradict stimulated emission at a particular frequency? For example BB radiation isn't coherent but stimulated emission is.

My guess is what we see is not $u(\omega)$ but something else.

Comment: BB radiation comes from a body that is thermal equilibrium and a laser is not in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: Sure the matter part by itself isn't in thermal equilibrium, but the matter and radiation are in thermal equilibrium right? I mean how else would we use Planck's law? Also A and B coefficients are derived under the assumption of thermodynamic equilibrium(which implies thermal equilibrium) as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients).

Comment: I will point out that the laser (object) is emitting blackbody radiation because, as you say, it is matter at a temperature. The actual laser-light output is not black body, and is not in equilibrium with anything. Just like many other things, including FM radio broadcast towers which are pumping out radio waves that are not black body radiation.

Answer (score 1):

The [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) is an idealized formula derived for a cavity with electromagnetic radiation. There are no bound states in this derivation, or atoms or molecules. The quantization comes from quantizing the radiation inside the box.

The best fit to the  black body formula on earth is from the [Cosmic Microwave Background CMB.,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Features) which is just photons from the decoupling of radiation from matter.

All other "fits" are approximate, exactly because the spectra of the atoms and molecules composing a real body of matter are independently observed. Nevertheless it is a useful tool for estimating temperatures of stars for example. See [the spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance) of the sun

[image: sunrad]

The small peaks in the incoming yellow curve  are due to the discreet  spectra of various atoms, but the black body curve is useful in getting a value for the temperature of the sun.

So in the case of the laser, the black body radiation curve of the mass composing it will be so small because the energy of the created beam coming from the spectral radiation is huge .

Black body radiation and spectral radiation are two different mechanisms by which radiation is created.( at the atomic level of matter it is the lattice vibrations/rotations in solids in the spill over fields of the atoms that create the black body  radiation).